# Use of "Busca con qué desaburrirte" to mean "Find something to entertain yourself"

Tags: traducción

The phrase "*busca con qué desaburrirte*" is a translation of "find something to entertain yourself" from a dubbed Latin American Spanish (not sure which country in particular) version of Shrek 2. Is this a common way of saying "find something to..."? I have never heard it said in Spain.

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hahjAhR7JFk&t=95) of the scene on youtube. The moment I am referring to is at 1:40.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all notice that "qué" is in a question, so the accent important,

> Busca con qué desaburrirte.

It sounds perfectly good to me to say "Busca con qué" + verb, but maybe in Spain is not that common. I would rather say "Busca algo para" + verb, so

> Busca algo para desaburrirte.

Notice also that "desaburrirse" doesn't mean exactly "entertain yourself", the literal translation will be "entretenerte", and it would be also perfectly fine to say

> Busca con qué entretenerte / Busca algo para entretenerte.

"Desaburrir" would literally mean "get unbored".

Answer (score 0):

It's a pun, based on the bored character being a donkey, which is similar to *burro*.

Even translators get to have some fun sometimes.